# Prolog - first list is sublist of second list?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

For example:

```
isin([1,2,3], [1,0,1,2,3,0])
```

will yield true because `123` is inside of `101230`

I wrote the following code:

```
isin([AH|AT],[AH|AT]).

isin([AH|AT],[BH|BT]):- AH = BH, isin(AT,BT), isin([AH|AT],BT).
```

seems not working. Try not to use any built-in functions and BTW, Prolog has a built-in `sublist(L1, L2)` function.

How do I write a query against a built-in function using SWI-Prolog ? I tried to directly write:

```
?- sublist([1],[2]).
```

but it returns an `undefined procedure` error.

Also, is it possible to see how a built-in function is coded and how ?

Comment: Try to ask one question at a time, please. And why should we try not to use any built-in predicates in your first question?

Comment: @svick I didn't want to waste several posts for my own question.

Comment: @user, please, do that. This is not a forum and each question should be just that: *a* question. For example, it's quite likely that different people would want to answer different parts of your current question. And maybe they won't bother if they don't know all the answers.

Comment: @svick Ok, if that's the preferred way. I'll do like you said in future post. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this was homework? That would explain why we should not use built-ins and why looking at the source code of a built-in helps the OP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sublist( [], _ ).
sublist( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
sublist( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X|XS], XSS ).
```

Comment: With this definition `sublist([1,2,3], [0,1,0,2,0,3,0]).` is true.

Comment: Any hint on how to achieve what @starblue is saying? I want to recognise only [1,2,3] for example.

Comment: This is not the definition of `sublist`, this is the definition of `subset`. For instance, with your definition `sublist(X, [a, b, c])` returns `X = [], [a], [a, b], [a, b, c], [a, c], [b], [b, c], [c]`. `[a, c]` is not a sublist but a subset of `[a, b, c]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want

```
my_sublist( [2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5] )
```

...to succeed, but

```
my_sublist( [1,3,5], [1,2,3,4,5] )
```

...to fail, you might want to consider

```
my_sublist( Sublist, List ) :-
    append( [_, Sublist, _], List ).
```

Note that if you pass a variable through as Sublist, backtracking will give you a comprehensive set of all possible sublists of List, but this will in general include several repeats of the empty list (because the empty list can combine with all other sublists both ahead and behind of them in an append operation).

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems to be homework I will only give you a few hints:

- It seems you are missing the case where an empty list is a sublist of the other one.
- You mixed the two cases "the sublist starts here" and "the sublist starts later" into one clause.
- It seems the elements of the sublist should be consecutive in the larger list. For that you need two predicates. Essentially you have to remember that the sublist has started when you take apart the lists.

There is no builtin `sublist/2`, only a `sublist/3` which does something different (filter list with a predicate).

Answer (score 1):

another implementation using member is :

```
sublist([],_).
sublist([X|Xs],Y) :- member(X,Y) , sublist(Xs,Y).
```

member/2 returns true if find the element in a list

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|Ys]):-member(X,Ys).
```

Comment: This is incorrect: `sublist(X, [a, b, c])` returns `[], [a], [a, a], [a, a, a], [a, a, a, a], …`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sublist(S, L) :-length(S, N),
                length(L, N1),
                N2 is N1 - N,
                length(P, N2),
                append( _ , S, P), 
                append(P, _ , L).
```

to avoid stack overflow for failing cases we must determine the size of the list `P`.

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications to [ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053979), this is something that works,

```
preList([], L).
preList([H_s|T_s], [H_s|Tail]):-
    preList(T_s, Tail).

subList([H_s|T_s], [H_s|Tail]):-
    preList(T_s, Tail).

subList([H_s|T_s], [H_s|Tail]):-
    subList([H_s|T_s], Tail).
    
subList(Sub, [_|Tail]):-
    subList(Sub, Tail).
```

Essentially, look for a match between the first elements of the sub-list and the main-list using the `subList` procedure. When a match occurs, head over to the `preList` procedure and check if this turns out to be a prefix for the remainder of the list. If so, the resolution ends in success.

If not, come back and continue comparing the remainder of the list for a first-element match.

Answer (score 0):

```
sublist([],[],_):-!.
sublist(_,[],_):-!.

sublist([H1|T1],[H2|T2],LV):-
H1 = H2,!,
sublist(T1,T2,LV).

sublist([H1|T1],[H2|_],LV):-
not(H1 = H2),
sublist(T1,LV,LV).
```

If you try these queries:

```
?-sublist([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]).
TRUE

?-sublist([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,4],[1,2,4]).
FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% prefix: Is the first list the prefix of the second?
% True if the two have the same head and the tail of the first
% is the prefix of the tail of the second.
prefix([X|T], [X|R]) :- prefix(T, R).
% True if the first list is the empty list.
prefix([], _).

% sublist: Is the first list a sublist of the second list?
% True if the two lists start with the same element and
% the tail of the first is a prefix of the tail of the second.
sublist([X|T], [X|R]) :- prefix(T, R), !.
% True if the first list is a sublist of the tail of the second.
sublist(L, [_|R]) :- sublist(L, R).
% True if the first list is the empty list.
sublist([], _).
```