# How to check if a list is a non-empty sublist of another list in Prolog

Tags: prolog, sublist

I am trying to create an `included_list(X,Y)` term that checks if X is a non-empty sublist of Y.

I already use this for checking if the elements exist on the Y list

```
check_x(X,[X|Tail]).
check_x(X,[Head|Tail]):- check_x(X,Tail).
```

And the append term

```
append([], L, L).
append([X | L1], L2, [X | L3]) :- append(L1, L2, L3).
```

to create a list, in order for the program to finish on

```
included_list([HeadX|TailX],[HeadX|TailX]).
```

but I am having problems handling the new empty list that I am trying to create through "append" (I want to create an empty list to add elements that are confirmed to exist on both lists.)

I have found this

```
sublist1( [], _ ).
sublist1( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist1( XS, XSS ).
sublist1( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist1( [X|XS], XSS ).
```

but it turns true on sublist([],[1,2,3,4)

Comment: if is a sublist contemplating the order? or order doesn't matter. ?

Comment: could you elaborate more "but I am having problems handling the new empty list that I am trying to create through "append""? handling what? how do you create the empty list and what do you use it for?

Comment: You might want to see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051400/prolog-first-list-is-sublist-of-second-list

Comment: @user2520215 this does work for empty sublists.

Comment: @LeleDumbo I want to create an empty list to add elements that are confirmed to exist on both lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're looking for a *non-contiguous sublist* or *ordered subset*, and not wanting to include the empty list, then:

```
sub_list([X], [X|_]).
sub_list([X], [Y|T]) :-
    X \== Y,
    sub_list([X], T).
sub_list([X,Y|T1], [X|T2]) :-
    sub_list([Y|T1], T2).
sub_list([X,Y|T1], [Z|T2]) :-
    X \== Z,
    sub_list([X,Y|T1], T2).
```

Some results:

```
| ?- sub_list([1,4], [1,2,3,4]).

true ? a

no
| ?- sub_list(X, [1,2,3]).

X = [1] ? a

X = [2]

X = [3]

X = [1,2]

X = [1,3]

X = [1,2,3]

X = [2,3]

(2 ms) no
| ?- sub_list([1,X], [1,2,3,4]).

X = 2 ? a

X = 3

X = 4

(2 ms) no
```

Note that it doesn't just tell you if one list is a sublist of another, but it answers more general questions of, for example, *What are the sublists of `L`?* When cuts are used in predicates, it can remove possible valid solutions in that case. So this solution avoids the use of cut for this reason.

Explanation:

The idea is to generate a set of rules which define what a sublist is and try to do so without being procedural or imperative. The above clauses can be interpreted as:

1. `[X]` is a sublist of the list `[X|_]`
2. `[X]` is a sublist of the list `[Y|T]` if `X` and `Y` are different and `[X]` is a sublist of the list `T`. The condition of `X` and `Y` different prevents this rule from overlapping with rule #1 and greatly reduces the number of inferences required to execute the query by avoiding unnecessary recursions.
3. `[X,Y|T1]` is a sublist of `[X|T2]` if `[Y|T1]` is a sublist of `T2`. The form `[X,Y|T1]` ensures that the list has at least two elements so as not to overlap with rule #1 (which can result in any single solution being repeated more than once).
4. `[X,Y|T1]` is a sublist of `[Z|T2]` if `X` and `Z` are different and `[X,Y|T1]` is a sublist of `T2`. The form `[X,Y|T1]` ensures that the list has at least two elements so as not to overlap with rule #2, and the condition of `X` and `Z` different prevents this rule from overlapping with rule #3 (which can result in any single solution being repeated more than once) and greatly reduces the number of inferences required to execute the query by avoiding unnecessary recursions.

Comment: Could you please explain how your code works?
Seems to work fine though :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am new to prolog and it's difficult for me to understand recursion proccesses.
Did you edited anything in the code?

Comment: @Crownless - FYI I think user2520215's answer now works just as well and is more concise.

Comment: True, but I really like your explanation.

Comment: Could the last 2 rules be like : 
`sub_list([X|T1], [X|T2]) :- sub_list(T1, T2).
sub_list([X|T1], [Z|T2]) :- X \== Z, sub_list([X|T1], T2).`

Comment: @Crownless see my explanations #3 and #4 regarding why the form `[X,Y|T1]` is used. It avoids overlap with other rules, which would result in repeated solutions. So, using your suggested changes, the query `sub_list([1], [1,2])` would match both rule #1 and rule #3, And the query, `sub_list([1,4], [1,2,3,4]).` succeeds 4 times instead of just once, even though `[1,4]` really is only a sublist *once* in `[1,2,3,4]`. In other words, the predicate doesn't provide correct results.

Comment: So, your code will give no duplicate (or more) answers in any given situation, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you an do:

```
mysublist(L,L1):- sublist(L,L1), notnull(L).

notnull(X):-X\=[].

sublist( [], _ ).
sublist( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
sublist( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X|XS], XSS ).
```

Taking a reference from this:
[Prolog - first list is sublist of second list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051400/prolog-first-list-is-sublist-of-second-list)
I just added the condition to check if it was empty beforehand.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be the answer to my problem :)

Comment: If you could explain this code to me and how it works I would be so thankful. :)

Comment: `mysublist(S, [1,2,3])` returns false, so it says that `[1,2,3]` has no sublists, `S`.

Comment: @user2520215 Could you  add an explanation to the last 3 sublist rules, like lurker did?

Comment: Rather: `mysublist(L,L1) :- L = [_|_], sublist(L,L1).` and the name sublist is most unfortunate, use [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If order matters. Example `[1,2,3]` is  sublist of  `[1,2,3,4]` but `[1,3,2]` not.

You can do something like this.

```
sublist([],L).
sublist([X|L1],[X|L2]):- sublist(L1,L2)
```

Comment: Order does matter.
But your code doesnt work for [1,4] and [1,2,3,4]

Comment: @Crownless ok, check my answer, you can use something like that. It will return True, if first list is sublist of second one.

Comment: This only works if the sublist starts at the first position. In other words, `sublist([1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]) would fail.

Comment: @schrobe I asked if the order matters because that.

Comment: Then, that's not my case,

Answer (score 0):

I would use append :

```
sublist(X, []) :-
    is_list(X).


sublist(L, [X | Rest]) :-
    append(_, [X|T], L),
    sublist(T, Rest).
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically we can check if M is a sublist of L if M exists in L by appending something on its back and/or its front.

```
append([], Y, Y).
append([X|XS],YS,[X|Res]) :- append(XS, YS, Res).

sublist(_, []).
sublist(L, M) :- append(R, _, L), append(_, M, R).
```