# list of repetitions of another list given the number of repetitions

Tags: prolog

im trying to build a predicate **itrepeats(all,part,num0,num)**

**"all"** is the complete list of repetitions of the **"part"** list. **"num"** is the number of repetitions of **"part"** in **"all"**, and **"num0"** increases by **"num"**

For example:

```
itrepeats(['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],0,R)
```

Output should be:

```
R=3
```

Another example:

```
itrepeats(['a','b','c','c','a','b','a','b','b'],['a','b','c'],0,R)
```

Output should be:

```
no
```

Another example with **"all"** empty:

```
itrepeats([],['a','b','c'],0,R)
```

Output should be:

```
R=0
```

I tried with this, but it doesnt work, even if is just for a list of two elements:

```
itrepeats([],[_],0,0).
itrepeats([A,B|R],[A,B|R2],0,N):-
    N is N-1,
    itrepeats(R,[A,B|R2],0,N).
```

I'm pretty sure it should be like that, executing the next iteration without the previous elements of the actual iteration until **"all"** is empty, but i dont get how to do it well. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051400/prolog-first-list-is-sublist-of-second-list/53580916 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155107/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-a-non-empty-sublist-of-another-list-in-prolog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

A common Prolog idiom is to use *helper predicates* that carry additional state as extra arguments. Here, we need an *accumulator* to count the matching sublists as we go, which we seed with 0 as its initial value:

```
number_of_sublists( [H|T] , SL , N ) :- number_of_sublists( [H|T], SL, 0, N ).
```

And the process if finding the matching sublists is pretty simple:

- If the desired sublist the prefix of the current list, tick the count by 1.
- Strip the head of the list and recurse down on the tail.
- When the list is empty, the value of the accumulator is the final tally of matching sublist.

To find if a list is a prefix of another list is pretty easy. Just match list items until the one list is empty. (And note that the empty list will be found as a prefix of ***every*** list.)

```
is_prefix_of( []     , _      ).   % once the prefix list is empty, we're done: the prefix list is the prefix of the other list.
is_prefix_of( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- % Otherwise, if the two lists share a common head,
    is_prefix_of(Xs, Ys).          % - then recurse down on the tails.
```

Putting it all together you get:

```
number_of_sublists( []    , _  , N , N ) .  % once the list is exhausted, we're done. The accumulator is the final tally.
number_of_sublists( [H|T] , SL , X , N ) :- % otherwise...
    ( is_prefix_of(SL, [H|T])               % - if the sublist is a prefix of the list
      -> X1 is X+1                          %   - then increment the accumulator by 1
      ;  X1 is X                            %   - else don't increment 
    ),                                      %
    number_of_sublists( T, SL, X1, N ).     % remove the head of the list and recurse down on its tail.
```

One might note that this can be accomplished much easier using `findall/3` and `append/3`, something like:

```
number_of_sublists( L, SL, N ) :- findall( SL , prefix_of(SL,L), Sls), length(SLs,N).

prefix_of( SL, L ) :-
  append( _  , Sfx , L   ) ,
  append( SL , _   , Sfx ).
```