# Prolog - first list is sublist of second list while maintaining order?

Tags: list, prolog, sublist

I want to check if elements of list L1 occur consecutively, and in the same order, in list L2.

For example - check([b,c],[a,b,c,d]) must return true while check([b,d],[a,b,c,d]) must return false

I looked at similar posts [Prolog - first list is sublist of second list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051400/prolog-first-list-is-sublist-of-second-list) and also tried out similar solutions but whenever i try to check if elements are present, i am unable to check if ordering is consecutive

```
check( [], _ ).
check( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
check( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X|XS], XSS ).
```

and if i try to check if ordering is correct then my code is breaking.

```
check( [], _ ).
check( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting problem! I'm surprised at how much code it took, so there may be a better solution than this.

First we need a helper to insist that a list is a prefix of another list. The base case is that we ran out of a prefix list; the inductive case is that the current items match and the remainder of both lists is a prefix match.

```
prefix([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- prefix(Xs, Ys).
prefix([], _).
```

Now finding a consecutive sublist amounts to searching down a list for prefix matches. If the current items match, then having a prefix is a match:

```
consecutive_sublist([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- prefix(Xs, Ys).
```

Otherwise, we just discard this element of the search target and try again on the sublist:

```
consecutive_sublist(Prefix, [_|Ys]) :- consecutive_sublist(Prefix, Ys).
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution using the de facto standard definition of the `append/3` predicate:

```
check(SubList, List) :-
    append(Prefix, _, List),
    append(_, SubList, Prefix).
```

Sample calls:

```
| ?- check([b,d],[a,b,c,d]).

no

| ?- check([b,c],[a,b,c,d]).

true ? ;
no

| ?- check([b,c],[a,b,c,d,b,c,f]).

true ? ;
true ? ;
no
```

We can also use this definition to generate sublist-list pairs:

```
| ?- check(SubList, List).

SubList = [] ? ;

List = [A|_]
SubList = [A] ? ;

List = [_|_]
SubList = [] ? ;

List = [A,B|_]
SubList = [A,B] ? ;

List = [_,A|_]
SubList = [A] ? ;

List = [_,_|_]
SubList = [] ? ;

List = [A,B,C|_]
SubList = [A,B,C] ? ;

List = [_,A,B|_]
SubList = [A,B] ? ;

...
```

This problem also gives you the opportunity to learn about *termination* properties of predicates. As an experiment, exchange the order of the `append/3` calls and then check what happens on backtracking for e.g. the two first sample calls.

Answer (score 3):

We can make use of [**`append/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) to write this with a one-liner:

```
subsequence(X, Y) :-
    append([_,X,_], Y).
```

or we can implement a `subsequence/4` that will unify two variables `Prefix` and `Suffix` with the list before and after the subsequence:

```
subsequence(X, Y, Prefix, Suffix) :-
    append([Prefix,X,Suffix], Y).
```

Here we thus have two don't care variables that will collect the prefix and suffix before and after the subsequence.